# Moms4Mom merge possibility?

Tags: discussion

Is there any possibility of the Mom4Moms community wanting to merge into parenting.stackexchange? Should we reach out to their community to discuss this or other possibilities?

Comment: Relevant thread from their meta: http://meta.moms4mom.com/questions/2/do-you-think-m4m-should-become-a-stackexchange-20-site-or-strike-out-with-one-of-the-clones

Comment: Doesn't look like they have really come to a solution, and that thread (stating that they had a year left) was started last april...

Comment: If you look at the very, very last suggestion there is a suggestion to move to SE 2.0, and there is a comment there from one of the founders of the site: "if the site went to StackExchange we would have to essentially give it away. After all of the work establishing the site and community we would be handing it over to someone else." I'm not familiar with the whole terms and conditions between 1.0 and 2.0. But it's their choice.

Comment: Maybe it's an ad-revenue thing?

Comment: @talon8 Bingo, was sitting here struggling to understand the sentiment and the actual tangible difference (besides additional functionality), but I think you may have hit the nail on the head.

Comment: @talon8, @Orbit, I'm not privy to the details, but I doubt that the ad-revenue amounts to much.

Comment: I'd actually be more shocked if it wasn't significant. The site has ads. Ads pay per load. They have a decent sized regular community. How do you think most websites (eg: blogs) become viable businesses?

Answer (score 10):

If m4m wants to come over here, I'm all for it. More content means more value to the users.

I'd not want to move *our* content to m4m because they're on the old, less functional SE platform. If I wanted to move there, I'd just sign up with them instead of coming here.

Comment: I expect that m4m don't want to come here, or else they would have upgraded to SE 2.0 already and *this* site would be redundant.

Comment: And, from looking at their [meta](http://meta.moms4mom.com/questions/206/what-changed-when-moms4mom-moved-hosting-providers-on-february-5th-2011) if they wanted to move to SE2.0 they wouldn't have switched hosting and changed platform to OSQA in February.

Answer (score 4):

I was one of the answerers on the Moms4Mom [meta thread](http://meta.moms4mom.com/questions/2/do-you-think-m4m-should-become-a-stackexchange-20-site-or-strike-out-with-one-of-the-clones) that talon8 mentioned.

At the time, I was pretty negative and critical - still smarting (vicariously) from the 1.0 -> 2.0 upheaval.

Subsequently, I came to a slightly more balanced view, and encouraged both parties to try and negotiate their way to *not* having competing sites. I don't know the ins and outs of the ensuing discussion, but I think the main sticking point was about ceding control of the *community* (more than the brand, content or advertising revenue).

Moms4Mom is a very *gentle* community compared to the often 'robust' tone on SE sites. I have no numbers, but I'd say that there are more ladies there (which can be both cause *and* effect of the gentleness). There are no subjective or wiki police, no rants, no comment-spats, no 'us and them'. The benevolent dictators *are* benevolent, because the site *is* their baby.

I would *love* for Moms4Mom to be on the SE platform, but if - as it appears - going it alone is the only way to protect the existing community, then that's sad, but so be it.

Comment: Regrettably, I feel I must confiscate your crystal ball :)

Comment: @Jeff, sorry, I don't get that joke :( Is it because my crystal ball works too well? Or because it doesn't work at all? :)

Comment: @Jeff, ok I get it now (I think). Touché...

Answer (score 2):

They went with an open source Q&A platform, so I doubt they'll want to merge with SE 2.0, they already have a nice community and are doing fine.

Answer (score 2):

As @Juan says, I don't think they're going to want to merge. They're already using a different system for their meta.

In particular there is a lot of talk that they feel their community doesn't fit in the SE mold. Lots of what they consider 'on topic' is 'off topic' per this site's definition. There was also some objection to the whole notion of an "expert" that a lot of the SE sites are based around... that they don't want experts, they want real practitioners.

Basically, I think they were using the SE1.0 platform for something different than what parenting-SE is, so while there is some overlap, there's a LOT of non-overlap that doesn't make sense to merge and/or wouldn't be welcome.

And while I wish them well in wherever they take moms4mom, after lurking in their community for a while, I'm happy to not merge and see us build a new community... especially if we can do a better job about being more inclusive.