# What happened with moms4mom.com, isn't there kinda a conflict of interest?

Tags: discussion

moms4mom.com (a stackexchange 1.0 website edit: at least, it started as one) seems to be in direct conflict with parenting.SE ...  Was that decided to be a non-issue, and for sites to compete, live, and die as they could?

Not that I don't appreciate SE sites & like 'em better, but it seems sad that all the existing effort on questions & answers there may come to waste.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moms4Mom merge possibility?](http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/33/moms4mom-merge-possibility)

Comment: @torbengb Not a duplicate; this question centrally addresses a perceived conflict of interest not addressed in the other question at all.

Comment: You're right, that's two distinct issues.

Comment: What conflict of interest would that be? Do you possibly mean that there is competition between the sites? That's true. Competition is good for us.

Comment: @Lennart See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/ ...  *"[...] Once again, our goal is to make the Internet a better place to get expert answers to your questions. **Competing with existing sites that do a great job of that is not in our mission.** [...]"*

Comment: @Chris: So not a conflict of interest at all then. If they are outside of the mission or not I don't know, but I don't think it's a problem.

Comment: Because "mom" is American English it will probably annoy the crap out of British English speakers who'll go to parenting instead. Plus you're excluding the male contingent :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer back to [blog.stackoverflow.com - Changes to Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/).  Quote:

> **Q: What if a new, community-created
>   site competes with my existing,
>   old-rules Stack Exchange?**
>
> If your existing Stack Exchange site
>   already has developed a substantial
>   community, we’ll encourage people to
>   go there, rather than creating yet
>   another Stack Exchange on the same
>   topic. Once again, our goal is to make
>   the Internet a better place to get
>   expert answers to your questions.
>   Competing with existing sites that do
>   a great job of that is not in our
>   mission.
>
> However, if your Stack Exchange site
>   does not have substantial traffic, we
>   reserve the right to create a new site
>   on the same topic.

My own thoughts & analysis:

- Technically, *"we [Stack Overflow] reserve the right*" covers the case at hand.
- But I would point out that [moms4mom.com](http://moms4mom.com) is, IMHO, a **well-functioning community** doing a **great job** and having sufficient traffic.  I'm personally surprised the proposal for [parenting.SE](http://parenting.stackexchange.com) has made it all the way to beta.  I was expecting it to be delayed – for a while, but not forever.
- However, a counter-point could be that once moms4mom.com moved off the Stack Exchange platform (to OSQA), it no longer fell under the first specific condition above, being *"If your existing **Stack Exchange** site already has developed..."*
- But I would point out that even on OSQA, moms4mom.com still "makes the Internet a better place."

I see no clear cut-and-dry answer, and I think both communities have **genuine, authentic goals**, so I think you're right in qualifying "conflict-of-interest" with **kinda**.

It's simply *unfortunate* that there are now two communities, but c'est la vie.

A wise man once wrote:

> *"Things are the way they are because they got that way."* - Gerald Weinberg

Comment: I agree with the facts and sentiments, including the "unfortunate" part.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a discussion here : [Moms4Mom merge possibility?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/moms4mom-merge-possibility)